# OSX Terminal "last" does not show more logins before todays

Tags: macos, login, logs

In Mac OSX 10.12.1, using Terminal

```
last
```

does not show logins before today? I did read the earlier article and tried

```
sudo last
```

which did not reveal anything earlier.

Comment: From a former responder that deleted their comment, it would seem this is because of logs prior to today being .gz compressed. Really? Is there not a single online capability to see all the logins in an OS X instance's history?

Comment: What are the results of- `syslog -k Sender login` ?

Comment: I deleted an answer that was not correct. According to `man wtmp` on macOS 10.12.1, "These files no longer exist in 10.5 or later. `/var/run/utmp`, `/var/log/wtmp`, `/var/log/lastlog`".

Comment: The result of the syslog confirms what Christopher is saying: `NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.`

Answer (score 1):

`last` works in Sierra like in all older OS X systems equipped with ASL.

Here is an example of a Sierra VM (<s>first light:</s> installed: Sep 20, 2016):

```
user  ttys001                       Fri Dec  9 02:31   still logged in
user  ttys000                       Fri Dec  9 02:30   still logged in
user  console                       Fri Dec  9 02:30   still logged in
...
reboot    ~                         Wed Sep 21 00:01 
user  console                       Tue Sep 20 22:18 - crash  (01:42)
reboot    ~                         Tue Sep 20 22:18 
user  ttys000                       Tue Sep 20 22:08 - crash  (00:09)
_mbsetupuser  console               Tue Sep 20 22:01 - crash  (00:17)
user  console                       Tue Sep 20 22:00 - crash  (00:17)
reboot    ~                         Tue Sep 20 21:59
```

You can check any misbehavior of last/ASL with Terminal.app:

Open a new shell and enter `sudo opensnoop -n last`, then open a tab with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and enter `last`.

In the first tab you should get something like:

```
  UID    PID COMM          FD PATH                 
  501   7281 last           3 /dev/dtracehelper    
  501   7281 last           3 /var/log/asl         
  501   7281 last           4 /var/log/asl/2016.12.04.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          -1 /var/log/asl/2016.12.04.U0.asl 
  501   7281 last           5 /var/log/asl/2016.12.04.U501.asl 
  501   7281 last           6 /var/log/asl/2016.12.05.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          -1 /var/log/asl/2016.12.05.U0.asl 
  501   7281 last           7 /var/log/asl/2016.12.05.U501.asl 
  501   7281 last           8 /var/log/asl/2016.12.06.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          -1 /var/log/asl/2016.12.06.U0.asl 
  501   7281 last           9 /var/log/asl/2016.12.06.U501.asl 
  501   7281 last          10 /var/log/asl/2016.12.08.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          -1 /var/log/asl/2016.12.08.U0.asl 
  501   7281 last          11 /var/log/asl/2016.12.08.U501.asl 
  501   7281 last          12 /var/log/asl/2016.12.09.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          -1 /var/log/asl/2016.12.09.U0.asl 
  501   7281 last          13 /var/log/asl/2016.12.09.U501.asl 
  501   7281 last          14 /var/log/asl/BB.2017.09.30.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          15 /var/log/asl/BB.2017.10.30.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          16 /var/log/asl/BB.2017.11.30.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          17 /var/log/asl/BB.2017.12.31.G80.asl 
  501   7281 last          18 /var/log/asl/Logs    
  501   7281 last          18 /var/log/asl/StoreData 
  501   7281 last           3 /etc/localtime       
  501   7281 last           3 /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
```

which shows all files opened/read by *last*. Quit opensnoop by entering: <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

If you don't get a similar output check your ASL subsystem (e.g. asl.conf or the launch daemons com.apple.syslogd/com.apple.aslmanager)/the folder /var/log/asl and repair everything if necessary.

Comment: Results from `opensnoop` on 10.12.1: `dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available` and 33 of these: `dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 5 (ID 188: syscall::open:return): invalid user access in action #11 at DIF offset 24`. 33 corresponds to the files shown in the answer. Why that message? Results from `last`: good logins since Sep, 2016. Why not since Sep 2015 when I first logged in (upgrades)? How do we find bad logins?

Comment: @Christopher I disabled SIP to get the opensnoop result. In my physical Mavericks install I get only the logins etc of the last ~one year (Dec 02, 2015-Dec 09, 2016) though I never reinstalled/deleted anything since Jan '14. You should convert your comment questions in one or several real ASE question here... ;-)

Comment: Regarding `_mbsetupuser` see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33391174/656912).